# Unable to change barplot width

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

I have the following code trying make a bar plot in python using seaborn, based simply on a two-column dataframe, with a "Category" column, and "Value" column with float values:

```
dataplot = sns.barplot(x = 'Category',
            y = 'Value',
            data = df, hue='Category')
```

This produces a bar plot plot with very skinny bars, going into both positive and negative values. I want to make the bars thicker/wider, and so I try to use the `width` parameter from seaborn, and I try:

```
dataplot = sns.barplot(x = 'Category',
            y = 'Value',
            data = df, hue='Category', width=2)
```

I am just testing out 2 as a value here for width, but I get this error that I do not understand:

```
TypeError: bar() got multiple values for argument 'width'
```

I do not understand what these multiple values is referring to. How can I correctly enter the `width` parameter into my bar plot code so that I can simply make my bars thicker?

Comment: `seaborn v0.12` has the `width` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I used a test dataset from seaborn and was able to recreate the same error as you...this is honestly really confusing to me as I also could not figure out the problem. But, in the meantime, I found a workaround to the problem that can be used.

```
width = 0.5
penguins= sns.load_dataset("penguins")
dataplot = sns.barplot(data=penguins, y="body_mass_g", x='island')
for bar in dataplot.patches:
    x = bar.get_x()
    width = bar.get_width()
    centre = x + width / 2.
    bar.set_x(centre - width / 2.)
    bar.set_width(width)  # set new width to 0.5
```

You should be able to use this with your code, although again, I'm confused why you ran into this error in the first place.

Comment: This got the bars thicker like I wanted, but then the legend disappears. And when I add the argument `hue=island`, then the legend returns, but my bars are too skinny again. I am not sure what is happening. But thank you for this solution, it did get the bars thicker.

Comment: you could always default to using matplotlib's interface for more control and just use seaborn styles. this is what I tend to do as I find seaborn to be too restrictive in many cases.